# Scan the DOM upward to find element matching selector (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors

I wanted a function that could scan the DOM upward from a `DOMElement` and also scan the children of each parent as it's going up.

It had to keep going until it would found any `<element>` matching the selector received in parameter. The selector had to be any type of valid CSS selector.

**It was also needed to be done in pure JS (no jQuery)**

Comment: This really isn't a proper question as outlined in the [help]. It is really only a goal with no specific code related problem statement

Comment: @Bram Vanroy: querySelector/All isn't going to be able to match an element's ancestors.

Comment: I now realise that OP is only looking at the ancestors' children, not all their descendants. (Which makes sense - otherwise you could just do a querySelector on ROOT.)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a modified version of this function that [I found on this site](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-the-closest-parent-element-with-a-matching-selector-using-vanilla-javascript/). You can use this function as you wish, scale it up, claim it yours, whatever you want.

### Here's the solution I found

```
GetClosest = function (elem, selector) {

    for (; elem && elem !== document.body; elem = elem.parentNode) {

        // If the elem matches at first iteration.
        if(elem.matches(selector)) {

            return elem;

        } else {

            // Scans all the childs of current iterated element (always higher in DOM until found).
            // If one matches the selector it'll stop and return it.
            child = elem.parentNode.firstChild;
            do {

                if(child.nodeType === 3) continue; // text node
                if(child.matches(selector)) return child;

            } while (child = child.nextElementSibling);
        }
    }

    return null;

};
```